# Load JSON file using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I just started learning Angular and I've looked on SO for a solution to load a JSON file using angular and I've done what other people have posted a solutions but I cannot get the data from my json file to show for some reason.

my json file (test.json) is simple:

```
{
    "array": [
        {"thing": "thing1"},
        {"thing": "thing2"},
        {"thing": "thing3"}
    ],

    "name": "robert"
}
```

this is my js file:

```
var myMod = angular.module("myMod", []);

myMod.controller("myCont", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.thing = "hi";

    $http.get("/test.json")
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.stuff = data.array;
                $scope.name = data.name;
            })
            .error(function (data) {
                console.log("there was an error");
            });
});
```

and i'm trying to just display the name like this but only `{{name}}` shows:

```
<html ng-app="myMod">
    <head>
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <script src="testing.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="myCont">
        {{stuff}}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what does your network tools show?

Comment: Add a console.log in the .success to see if it is called

Comment: nothing appeared in the console.  the error was `error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $htmlProvider <- $html <- myCont`

Comment: @winsticknova check at the answer added below..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you had typo, you should inject `$http`(responsible to make an ajax call) dependency instead of `$html`(doesn't exist in angular)

You should change code this way.

```
myMod.controller("myCont", function ($scope, $html) {
```

to

```
myMod.controller("myCont", function ($scope, $http) {
```

Comment: yeah that worked! don't know why I was typing `$html`

Comment: I think you are missed $html

Answer (score 0):

As Pankaj Parkar has stated, $http is what you need.

Here is a plunker I created with it working: http://plnkr.co/edit/d0DDU29uitMcwK6qA7kx?p=preview

app.js file with $http instead of $html:

```
var myMod = angular.module("myMod", []);

myMod.controller("myCont", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.thing = "hi";

    $http.get("test.json")
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.stuff = data.array;
                $scope.name = data.name;
            })
            .error(function (data) {
                console.log("there was an error");
            });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone trying this is getting the error:

```
$http.get(…).success is not a function
```

Apparently the syntax changed for Angular >1.6. The accepted answer here has new syntax: [$http.get(...).success is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169385/http-get-success-is-not-a-function)