# $http.get(...).success is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, function

i have this code:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
  $http.get('api/url-api')
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config){
     }
}
```

In my local enviroment, works ok, but in a server, return this error:

> TypeError: $http.get(...).success is not a function

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: what version on local envm and on server? btw, [_$http.get_](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get) return HttpPromise, so you need use _then_ instead

Comment: have you checked that all your javascripts loads in the server environment?

Comment: its `then()` not `success()`

Comment: Grundy, Version is v1.5.8, bansi Yes, all javascript are loaded. Thanks!

Comment: @AlejoRibes, 1.5.8 on both environment? are you sure, that on local and server **same** code?

Comment: Grundy, yes, is the same code

Comment: Look at the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: The `.success` syntax was correct up to Angular v1.4.3. See the old docs here: https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/docs/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: and officially removed in v.1.6

Answer (score 244, accepted):

The `.success` syntax was correct up to Angular v1.4.3.

For versions up to Angular v.1.6, you have to use `then` method. The `then()` method takes two arguments: a `success` and an `error` callback which will be called with a response object.

Using the `then()` method, attach a `callback` function to the returned `promise`.

Something like this:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
   $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'api/url-api'
   }).then(function (response){

   },function (error){

   });
}
```

See reference [here.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

`Shortcut` methods are also available.

```
$http.get('api/url-api').then(successCallback, errorCallback);

function successCallback(response){
    //success code
}
function errorCallback(error){
    //error code
}
```

The data you get from the response is expected to be in `JSON` format.
**JSON** is a great way of transporting **data**, and it is easy to use within **AngularJS**

The major difference between the 2 is that `.then()` call returns a `promise` (resolved with a value returned from a `callback`) while `.success()` is more traditional way of registering `callbacks` and doesn't return a `promise`.

Comment: I tryed with .then and works ok, thanks Alexandru-Ionut Mihai

Comment: `.success` and `.then` take different param, account for that

Comment: If re-writing the existing code, it may be easy to present the two arguments-functions (success, error) mentioned above in-line, and not separately like in the example.

Comment: "$resource(...).get(...).then is not a function" ...
Why is angularJS so crappy when it comes to consistency?

Answer (score 9):

This might be redundant but the above most voted answer says `.then(function (success)` and that didn't work for me as of Angular version `1.5.8`. Instead use `response` then inside the block `response.data` got me my json data I was looking for.

```
$http({
    method: 'get', 
    url: 'data/data.json'
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response, 'res');
    data = response.data;
},function (error){
    console.log(error, 'can not get data.');
});
```

Comment: i mean... did you try `success.data`? the  parameter name isn't that important in this case.

Comment: My code works. When I followed the above answer I got stuck. It is also an answer with a way to actually get the data and log it to your console. This can show developers how to test their data in their browser. I was led here by the same exact error in the question headline.

Comment: old code `$http.get('data/data.json').success(function(data) { data = data;}` with my answer a developer now knows its `data.data` can't just get data by itself. hence my answer is important to this error message.

Comment: The variable name will not make any difference, it could be `success.data` or `response.data` or anything else. You could even use          `donaldTrump.data` that will work too.  Although you should use sensible variable names, not sure this one will make much sense.

Comment: This is because the **success** object has an array named `data` that holds the data coming as response from your server. you need to access that data array, using  `<yourSuccessObjectName>.data`

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to use AngularJs 1.6.6 as of 21/10/2017  the following parameter works as .success and has been depleted. The .then() method takes two arguments: a response and an error callback which will be called with a response object.

```
 $scope.login = function () {
        $scope.btntext = "Please wait...!";
        $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: '/Home/userlogin', // link UserLogin with HomeController 
            data: $scope.user
         }).then(function (response) {
            console.log("Result value is : " + parseInt(response));
            data = response.data;
            $scope.btntext = 'Login';
            if (data == 1) {
                window.location.href = '/Home/dashboard';
             }
            else {
            alert(data);
        }
        }, function (error) {

        alert("Failed Login");
        });
```

The above snipit works for a login page.