# Error with $http.get in angularJS -- Success not a Function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http, angularjs-1.6

Getting this error:

> angular.min.js:122 TypeError: $http.get(...).success is not a function
>       at getUserInfo (app.js:7)
>       at new  (app.js:12)
>       at Object.invoke (angular.min.js:43)
>       at Q.instance (angular.min.js:93)
>       at p (angular.min.js:68)
>       at g (angular.min.js:60)
>       at g (angular.min.js:61)
>       at g (angular.min.js:61)
>       at angular.min.js:60
>       at angular.min.js:21

Here is my code:

```
var gitHub = angular.module('gitHub', []);

gitHub.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    var $scope.user = '';
    function getUserInfo($scope, $http){ 
        $http.get('https://api.github.com/users')
            .success(function (result) {
                $scope.user = result;
                console.log(result);
            });
    };
    getUserInfo($scope, $http);
}]);
```

and here is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="gitHub">
<head>
    <title>Github Users Directory</title>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="mainController">
        <div>
            <h1>GitHub Users</h1>
            Who do you want to search for?<input type="text" name="FindHim" ng-model="queryName" />
            <button ng-click="getUserInfo()">Search</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            {{ user }}
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which version of angular?

Comment: The `success` and `error` callbacks are deprecated since (I think) angular 1.5

Comment: The `.success` and `.error` methods are deprecated and have been [removed from AngularJS 1.6](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrate1.5to1.6-ng-services-$http).

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The `.success` and `.error` methods are deprecated and have been [removed from AngularJS 1.6](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrate1.5to1.6-ng-services-$http). Use the standard `.then` method instead.

```
$http.get('https://api.github.com/users')
  .then(function (response) {

    var data = response.data;
    var status = response.status;
    var statusText = response.statusText;
    var headers = response.headers;
    var config = response.config;

    $scope.user = data;
    console.log(data);
});
```

> ### Deprecation Notice
>
> The `$http` legacy promise methods `.success` and `.error` have been deprecated and will be removed in v1.6.0. Use the standard `.then` method instead.
>
> [— AngularJS (v1.5) $http Service API Reference -- Deprecation Notice](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.10/docs/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice).

Also see [SO: Why are angular $http success/error methods deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35331339/5535245).

Answer (score 15):

i think you need to use .then and not .success when using [angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Example from the doc's

```
var promise = asyncGreet('Robin Hood');
promise.then(function(greeting) {
  alert('Success: ' + greeting);
}, function(reason) {
  alert('Failed: ' + reason);
}, function(update) {
  alert('Got notification: ' + update);
});
```

Here is the example of how $Http uses it:

```
// Simple GET request example:
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

And finally your code could look like this

```
$scope.getUserInfo = function () {
    $http.get('https://api.github.com/users')
        .then(function (result) {
            $scope.user = result;
            console.log(result);
        }, function(result) {
            //some error
            console.log(result);
        });
};
```

Comment: They don't **need** to use `.then()` although they should as `.success()` is deprecated. You should probably give an example though that uses `$http` with `.then()` rather than a generic promise example.

Answer (score 4):

this works

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

```js
// Simple GET request example:
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

As per your current implementation, You  are not passing arguments (i.e. `$scope` and `$http`) to `getUserInfo` from `ng-click="getUserInfo()"` thus you are getting the error.

You don't need to pass these as arguments as `$scope` and `$http` as its already injected in controller and define the function in `$scope`.

```
gitHub.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.user = '';
    //Redefined function, without arguments
    $scope.getUserInfo = function (){ 
        $http.get('https://api.github.com/users')
            .success(function (result) {
                $scope.user = result;
                console.log(result);
            });
    };
    $scope.getUserInfo();
}]);
```

Comment: Dont, same error, although I'm able to do it with using .then instead of .success method

Comment: Borrowed your code to give him an example using .then

Comment: @devzero, Never mind

Comment: @ManzurKhanSarguroh, Which version of `angular` you are using?

Comment: @Satpal version 1.6

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to inject $scope, $http..

```
app.controller('MainController', function($scope, $http) { 
  $scope.fetchData = function(_city){
    $http.get("../api/AllPlaces?filter[where][placeCity]="+ _city)
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.Data = response.data;
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to pass $http as a function parameter, since you have already injected $http as a dependency to your controller. I have made some modification to the code. Please check it will work fine for you.

```
var gitHub = angular.module('gitHub', []);

gitHub.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.user = '';

    $scope.getUserInfo = function() {
        $http.get('https://api.github.com/users')
            .success(function (result) {
                $scope.user = result;
                console.log(result);
            });
    };
    $scope.getUserInfo();
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '....',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage["token"]
    }
})
.then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
     alert(JSON.stringify(data) + "Status" + status);
})
.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
     alert(JSON.stringify(data) + "Status" + status);
});
```

Comment: please format your code properly

Comment: The `.error` method is deprecated. Instead use `.catch`.

Answer (score 0):

According to Angular JS `$http` [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), this system has been excludede from `1.4.3 +` So, I have taken help from his [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169385/http-get-success-is-not-a-function) and you can try this way

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
   $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'api/url-api'
   }).then(function (success){

   },function (error){

   });
}
```

OR

```
$http.get('api/url-api').then(successCallback, errorCallback);

function successCallback(response){
    //success code
}
function errorCallback(error){
    //error code
}
```

I prefer the second one which was more flexible for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
function successCallback(response) {
return response
}
$http.get('url')
.then(successCallback)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.