# AngularJs- TypeError: (…).success is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been working on a project and get this error that i cant solve.

```
angular.js:14525 
    TypeError: EmpApi.getEmployees(...).success is not a function
    at getEmployees (demo.js:146)
    at new <anonymous> (demo.js:144)
    at Object.instantiate (angular.js:5018)
    at $controller (angular.js:10881)
    at Object.link (angular-route.js:1214)
    at angular.js:1346
    at invokeLinkFn (angular.js:10426)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:9815)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:9055)
    at publicLinkFn (angular.js:8920) "<div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

Demo.js that i am using

```
MyApp.controller("HomeController", function ($scope, EmpApi) {

    getEmployees();
    function getEmployees() {
        EmpApi.getEmployees().success(function (emps) {
            $scope.emps = emps;

        })
        .error(function(error){
            $scope.status = 'Unable to load emp data:' + error.message;

        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you show your code? And more specifically the `getEmployees` function.

Comment: Probably forgot to `return` a `$http` object  from `EmpApi.getEmployees()`. Show the relevant code

Comment: i added the code above

Comment: which angular.js version are you using?  This is *definitely* **expected behavior** in angular.js 1.6

Comment: I am using AngularJS v1.6.4 but dont know how to change my .success and .error function

Comment: See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating to v1.6 - http](https://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/docs/guide/migration#migrate1.5to1.6-ng-services-$http)

Comment: See also [Error with $http.get in angularJS — Success not a Function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183845/error-with-http-get-in-angularjs-success-not-a-function/41187435#41187435).