# Don't know how AngularJS is intalled in my app and I need update it

Tags: angularjs, version, upgrade

I have an application that uses AngularJS v1.2.12 but we aren't the people that created. I've searched everywhere how to upgrade v1.2.12 to v1.7.0 but it seems that in installed in a different way.
All I've seen is "update bower.json file" or "update package.json file" but the angular folders are in "app\libs\frameworks\angular" and doesn't has any of those files... 
So I don't know if I should change the version manually or run some commands, but I've installed NodeJS and Angular CLI and it throws the same error when I try "ng -update" it says that it wasn't found the package.json file.

Even in the official page I didn't found anything.

Do you have any clue about this?

---

I've a `ViewBag.IsDebug == false` that use a `XXXFramework.js` that seems to be inner of the solution, but in case is `ViewBag.IsDebug == true` it uses

```
<script src="app/libs/frameworks/angular/angular.min.js"></script> 
<script src="app/libs/frameworks/angular/angular-animate.js"></script> 
<script src="app/libs/frameworks/angular/angular-cookies.min.js"></script> 
<script src="app/libs/frameworks/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script> 
<script src="app/libs/frameworks/moment/angular-moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: What does index.html look like? Does it have angular lib in it's own script tag perhaps? Anything built with `1.2` long precedes existence of Angular CLI and more likely used grunt or gulp as task runner if it wasn't just built manually

Comment: If it was built using grunt or gulp good chance you'll see injection comments in index file also

Comment: I've a ViewBag.IsDebug == false that use a XXXFramework.js that seems to be inner of the solution, but in case is ViewBag.IsDebug == true it uses

            <script src="app/libs/frameworks/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="app/libs/frameworks/angular/angular-animate.js"></script>
            <script src="app/libs/frameworks/angular/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
            <script src="app/libs/frameworks/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
            <script src="app/libs/frameworks/moment/angular-moment.js"></script>

Comment: `ViewBag` sounds like an ASP .Net thing. You could use CDN versions of the files shown though and upgrade that way. https://code.angularjs.org/

Comment: How can I use CDN versions? I mean, I download and replace them in my project folder?

Comment: That or use the remote CDN url directly in those script tags. One benefit of cdn versions is many users may already have them cached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script> 
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular-moment/angular-moment.js"></script>
```

Also be sure to read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating from Previous Versions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration).

Also

- [angularjs 1.6.0 (latest now) routes not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211875/angularjs-1-6-0-latest-now-routes-not-working/41213016#41213016)
- [Error with $http.get in angularJS -- Success not a Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183845/error-with-http-get-in-angularjs-success-not-a-function/41187435#41187435)
- [Why are AngularJS $http success/error methods deprecated? Removed from v1.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angularjs-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339)

---

> In the meantime i'm trying to start using angularjs 1.3

In that case use:

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular@1.3/angular.js"></script> 
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular-animate@1.3/angular-animate.js"></script> 
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular-cookies@1.3/angular-cookies.js"></script> 
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular-route@1.3/angular-route.js"></script> 
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular-moment/angular-moment.js"></script>
```

Also use `angular.js` instead of `angular.min.js`. It will enable [Data Debug](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production#disabling-debug-data) and provide better error messages.

Comment: Ooh yeah....numerous things going to break in big jump from 1.2 to latest

Comment: Yes I've read it before but only says what functions are deprecated and what are the updates of each new version. It doesn't has any data of what are the steps to follow to update it.
Even using NuGet, when I install the new version 1.7.0 it installed at Project level, not in the app/libs/framework path I said before

Comment: @MattDmc one thing that will almost certainly need fixing is the `$http` API deprecated `success` and `error` methods a long time ago in favor of promise `then()` and `catch()`

Comment: Ok, I will keep that in mind whenever I can update it. In the meantime i'm trying to start using angularjs 1.3 or something like that

Comment: Well something weird happened, when I add the "<script src="//unpkg.com/angular" scripts, all mi libraries have the word "Home" added and their aren't found.