# AngularJS: Directive to controller communication: $(http).get(...).success is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to send data from factory to a controller but I get the following error:

```
$(http).get(...).success is not a function
```

Factory code:

```
app.factory('sportsFactory', ['$http', function($http) {
  return $http.get('data/sports.json')
    .success(function(data) {
      return data;
    })
    .error(function(err) {
      return err;
    });
}]);
```

Controller code:

```
app.controller('NavbarController',['$scope', 'sportsFactory', 
    function($scope, sportsFactory){
       sportsFactory.success(function(data){
          $scope.sports = data;
       });
}]);
```

If I pass a data without using $http it works!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$http.get(...).success is not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169385/http-get-success-is-not-a-function)

Comment: @EddyG Which version of angular you are using?. If you are using angular 1.6 `.success`, `.error` methods are deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is better to create a factory method instead of returning one http request, because that way you can use same factory for several occasions like different http requests for example. But in here this factory only usable for this http request only. So create a function and call that method inside controller.

```
app.factory('sportsFactory', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        sendReq: function() {
            return $http.get('data/sports.json')
        }
    }
}]);
```

Note that you don't have to return the success inside the factory since the controller handling the response/promise.

call `sendReq` method from the controller like this

```
app.controller('NavbarController', ['$scope', 'sportsFactory',
    function($scope, sportsFactory) {
        sportsFactory.sendReq().success(function(data) {
            $scope.sports = data;
        });
    }
]);
```

Note that `success` is not available since angular 1.6. so beware of your version. if its a latest version use `then` instead of `success` like this

```
app.controller('NavbarController', ['$scope', 'sportsFactory',
        function($scope, sportsFactory) {
            sportsFactory.sendReq().then(function(response) {
                $scope.sports = response.data; // data comes under data property in then 
            });
        }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your factory code **just return the `http` promise**, and **handle it in your controller**.

```
app.factory('sportsFactory', ['$http', function($http) {
  return $http.get('data/sports.json')
}]);
```

If you return a `promise` from the `service`, **you can handle both success and error callbacks in your `controller`**.

Your controller will be,

```
app.controller('NavbarController',['$scope', 'sportsFactory', 
    function($scope, sportsFactory){
       sportsFactory.then(function(data) {
            $scope.sports = data;
    })
    .error(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
}]);
```

Use, `then` instead if `success` since `success` is deprecated in the latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.factory('sportsFactory', ['$http', function($http) {
  return $http.get('data/sports.json')
}]);
```

and in controller

```
app.controller('NavbarController',['$scope', 'sportsFactory', 
    function($scope, sportsFactory){
       sportsFactory.then(function(data){
          $scope.sports = data;
       });
}]);
```