# Return request response in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, promise

I've setup a controller and service to grab some JSON from my own NodeJS API/MongoDB endpoint.

In my browser console I see a returned object and 5 items and when I query my api I see the same json in the browser, so I know it's working on the server side.

I'm confused though about why when attempting to NG-Repeat through this I get nothing on page and when I console log out the returned data, it comes back undefined.

I'm new to the HTTP module and I'm trying to refactor out DB calls to a service instead of using it in controller.

--- Controller code ---

```
vm.getDepartments = function() {
        vm.departments = DbService.getAllDepartments();
        console.log(vm.departments);

    }();
```

--- Service Code (using $http) ---

```
function getAllDepartments() {
        $http.get('/api/departments').then(function(err, response) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            return response;

        });
    };
```

--- html page ---

```
<tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat='dept in vm.departments'>
                        <td>{{ dept.departmentLong }}</td>
                        <td>{{ dept.departmentShort }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button class='btn btn-warning'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></button>
                            <button class='btn btn-danger' ng-click='vm.deleteDepartment(dept);'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle'></span></button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used wrong `then` method.

The `then()` method takes two arguments: a `success` and an `error` callback which will be called with a `response` object.

Using the `then()` method, attach a `callback` function to the returned `promise`.

Have a look to an old answer posted by [mine.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169385/http-get-success-is-not-a-function/41169452#41169452)

`$http.get('/api/departments')` returns a **promise**, so you can create a function which returns only the promise,  as **@sachila ranawaka** mentioned.

```
function getAllDepartments() {
   return $http.get('/api/departments')
};
```

In the controller use **then** method which I mentioned above.

```
 DbService.getAllDepartments().then(function(response) {
      vm.departments = response.data; 
      console.log(vm.departments);
 },function(error){
      console.log(err);
 });
```

**Another method** is to create a `callback` function, and pass it to `getAllDepartments` method.

```
function getAllDepartments(callback) {
    $http.get('/api/departments').then(function(response) {
        callback(response);
    });
};
```

Controller code:

```
vm.getDepartments = function() {
    vm.departments = DbService.getAllDepartments(function(result){
        console.log(result);
    });
}();
```

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that that for handling a promises rejection (which is caused by an error) you can call the .catch() method on $http.get('/api/departments').

Comment: Thanks Alex. Your explanation was very helpful. It's now working and I think I understand the responsibility of the service a bit more. Promises have been a challenge for me, practice will help I think.

Answer (score 3):

in the service just return the http request

```
function getAllDepartments() {
       return $http.get('/api/departments')
 };
```

And catch the promise inside the controller. use  `response.data` to get the data

```
vm.getDepartments = function() {
      DbService.getAllDepartments().then(function(response) {

            vm.departments = response.data; 
            console.log(vm.departments);
        });

    }
```