# How to call a http Get service and dispaly its response in a div in angularjs on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to call a $http Get service on button click in angular js. But I am not getting the data to show in results... My code snippet is as follows:-

```
<button ng-controller="myCtrl6" ng-click="search()">Click</button>
<p ng-controller="myCtrl6">
  {{results}}
  {{fail}}
</p>
```

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller('myCtrl6', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.results = "";
  $scope.fail = "f";
  $scope.search = function() {
    $http.get('welcome.html', {}, function(response) {
      $scope.results = response.data; 
    }, function (failure) { 
      console.log("failed :(", failure); 
    });
  }
}]);
```

welcome.html

```
Hello World
```

Comment: Where did you call $scope.search function?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169385/http-get-success-is-not-a-function

Comment: then() function is required!

Comment: The shortcut method usage for $http is given in the docs:
$http.get('/someUrl', config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: I called $scope.search in <button ng-click="search()"> tag

Answer (score 1):

This is the proper use of $http

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // in your case 
    $scope.results = response.data; 
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

or

```
$http.get('/someUrl', config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Better make a service for this :

```
app.factory('ServiceName', function() {
  return {
     search: search
  };

  function search () {
    return $http.get('/someUrl', config);
  }
});
```

in controller

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller('myCtrl6', ['$scope', 'ServiceName', function ($scope, serviceName) {
  $scope.search = function() {
    serviceName.search().then(function(response) {
      $scope.results = response.data; 
    });
  }
}]);
```

Edited

Comment: where should I use this code is it inside controller ?

Comment: the name of your service, you can name it as you wish ... `SearchService` for example. It is up to you

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your button and p tag inside div(main container), by doing this you can access your controllers scope only inside that main container not outside of that.

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl6">
        <p >{{results}}
        {{fail}}
        </p>
        <button ng-click="search()">Fetch Data</button>
</div>
```

And in script.js file write

```
$scope.search = function () {                    
          $http.get('welcome.html')
          .success(function(response) {
            $scope.results = response;
          })
          .error(function(error) {
            console.log("error is : " + JSON.stringify(error))
          })
    }
```