# AngularJs - .success is not a function after minification

Tags: angularjs

I'm using angularJS(v1.5.7) in my MVC application. During the development, we used the syntax bellow to make ajax calling::

```js
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: "",
  params: { }
}).success(function (data) {
  ...
}).finally(function () {
  ...
});
```

When I published my application on the server, I'm using bundle to minify my javascript files.

After that, I'm geting the error: **".success is not a function"**

Does anybody knows why this issue happen only when I minify the files?

Comment: Can you able to run the application locally with above code snippet?

Comment: Yes. It's works.

Comment: Can you check below syntax and try to do minification

Comment: If I use "then" it's works well. The problem is change all my project.

Comment: Yes. You should follow the correct syntax. Do changes in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following syntax

```
.then(function(success)){  
    ...  
}, function(error){  
    ...  
});
```

As once answered here for more information.
[$http.get(...).success is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169385/http-get-success-is-not-a-function) the angular team deprecated success as a function itself in favour of using .then() and passing in first a success function, and a second optional error function passed in.

Comment: That would be a decision made from the angular team to allow for debugging/troubleshooting deprecated code while upgrading. A lot of rules aren't strictly enforced so your project and functions can still work in debug mode but not once moved into a production environment. 

It's unfortunate to have to change it in every location, but it's a much easier syntax to read, especially when you can move your success/error call backs seperated in code and just pass the function names in as parameters ex: .then(success, error); function success(response){return true;} etc.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax looks wrong.

Try below syntax.

```
    // Simple GET request example:
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/someUrl'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
       // this callback will be called asynchronously
       // when the response is available
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
       // called asynchronously if an error occurs
       // or server returns response with an error status.
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJS (v1.5.7) there is no any  `.success` event so instead of that in your version use `.then` for RESTAPI call

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/Url'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {

  }, function errorCallback(response) { 

  });
```

For more details you can visit this page 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http