# Querying Web API with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, html, asp.net-web-api

I've been following [this tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/single-page-application-using-web-api-and-angularjs/) and have the following controller:

```
(function (app) {
var MusicListController = function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("/api/Musics").then(function (data) {
        $scope.musics = data;
    },function (response){}
    );
};
app.controller("MusicListController", MusicListController);
}(angular.module("theMusic")));
```

module:

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module('theMusic', []);
}());
```

and html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Music App</title>
<script src="../../Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="../../Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/theMusic.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/MusicListController.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="theMusic">
    <div ng-controller="MusicListController">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Singers</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="music in musics">
                    <td>{{music.Title}}</td>
                    <td>{{music.Singers}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's supposed to display the results of an API request but currently all that is displayed is an empty table. I suspect my problem lies somewhere with my `$http.get.then` function as the tutorial used what seems to be a deprecated `$http.get.success` and [I looked up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169385/http-get-success-is-not-a-function) the new way of doing it.

If I go to (localhost)/api/musics while debugging it does return the XML file with the data in it.

Could someone help?

Thanks

Comment: first of all, look in dev tools ( F12 ), under network tab and see what your http call returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `$http.get("...").then()` what you get in the object passed as argument in the callback (function inside the `then`) is not the `data` itself but the whole HTTP response. So you have to access the `data` inside the response.

In your case, suppose the Web API responds like this: `{"musics": [{"author": "Jon Doe", "title": "abc"}]}` ... you need to do it like this:

```
$http.get("/api/Musics").then(function (response) {
    $scope.musics = response.data; // <-- here we are getting the object `data` which is inside the whole `response`
},function (response){}
);
```

This is different from the deprecated `$http.get.success` which, indeed, put the `data` (extracted from the HTTP response) as argument to the callback function.

Comment: Changing `$scope.musics = data;` to `$scope.musics = data.data;` did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should do data.data for collecting response:

```
var MusicListController = function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("/api/Musics").then(function (data) {
        $scope.musics = data.data;
    },function (response){}
    );
};
```