# Call $http inside AngularJS function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, http

I've been trying for a while to get the data from this call, but it always returns "undefined"

```
httpCall = function(sTformName) {
  let sURL = "https://urlthisone/api/",
  response; 

  $http.get(sURL)
    .success(function(data) {
      response = data;
    });
}
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When a JavaScript function lacks a [return statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) it returns `undefined`. That's the way JavaScript works.

Comment: Was my answer below able to help you out here? Please let me know. I'd like to help you resolve this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return and resolve the promise...

```
httpCall = function(sTformName) {
  let sURL = 'https://urlthisone/api/',
  return $http.get(sURL);
}
```

---

```
httpCall('myForm').then(response => {
  console.log(response.data);
});
```

[`$http.get`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get) is an asynchronous call and must be handled accordingly, in this case, by resolving the returned [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Why 'myForm'? Where does that come from?

Comment: It's just an example, since your function `httpCall` takes a parameter named `sTformName`. I'd imagine this means something to you...

Comment: Yes, sorry. This one did the trick! Hadn't been able to answer until now. Thanks!

Comment: happy to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

You're making an async call, and it will not return a value. It calls success and inside success you need to use a callback method in order to get the value you want, and work with it.

```
function doSomethingWithTheData(data) {
  // process the data here.
}

httpCall = function(sTformName, callback) {
    let sURL = "https://urlthisone/api/",
    response; 

    $http.get(sURL)
        .success(function(data) {
        callback(data); // here's where we call the callback
    });
}

// call it with the callback
httpCall(fornName, doSomethingWithTheData);
```

Comment: The `.success` method is [deprecated and removed from version 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angularjs-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339).

Comment: Also see [Why are Callbacks from Promise `.then` Methods an Anti-Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660881/why-are-callbacks-from-promise-then-methods-an-anti-pattern).

Comment: @georgeawg His initial example uses .success, so I was providing an answer that applied to his question.  Please do not down vote answers that both work, and pertain directly to the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

Please, see documentation - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get

According to it, if you use angular.js 1.4.3+, `$http.get(sURL)` returns promise. So you need `$http.get(sURL).then(...)`
Also, see [$http.get(...).success is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169385/http-get-success-is-not-a-function) might will help

Comment: The .success syntax was correct up to Angular v1.4.3  - so it depends on what version you're using.

Comment: @nixkuroi The `.success` method should be avoided even with older versions of AngularJS.